# Is there a command to click Browse button using Dragon Naturally Speaking Software?

Tags: speech-recognition, naturallyspeaking

I am very new to Dragon Naturally speaking software. And I mainly use it for web application. I am able to navigate to all the buttons and other elements but not 'Browse' button which is used to upload files. 
 I tried adding the attributes alt, title and name but dragon is not recognizing it. 
`<input type="file" title="Upload file" alt="Upload file" name="upload">`

Is there specific command to click the upload button? Or should we create custom command?

Answer (score 1):

If your browser is Microsoft Internet Explorer, and you know the ID of the "Browse" button, this code should click it for you:

```
Sub Main 
   Dim wb As Object '  prepare a web browser object 
   Set wb = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows.Item(0) '  set the wb object to the active window, namely Item(0) 
   wb.Visible = True '  wb must be visible to the code for it to act 
   wb.Document.getElementByID("the_exact_ID_name_of_the_element").click() '  the element ID can also be passed in as a variable 
   Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you don't have the element ID, you can select the item by index, or by class or control type, etc.